# Select mysql GROUP BY

Tags: php

Bom dia Amigos.
Estou com um problema em um select no mysql com group by.
Tenho um sistema de aposta q gera a posta em arrays gravando no banco cada uma das cotações apostadas q gera um código q de cupom.
MINHA DUVIDA É.
Como faço pra pegara um único registro desse grupo de mesmo código?

Answer (score 0):

Se compreendi bem, voce pode fazer assim "SELECT * FROM aposta WHERE codigo=XX LIMIT 1" Aqui e;e vai retornaruma aposta das que tem o mesmo código, porem nao entendi bem se vai ter uma condiçao a mais e ta;, se nao for isso comenta ai para eu te ajudar melhor!